# Why is the form "Did she have a big family" correct but "Did she has a big family" is not?

Tags: tense

Why do we say *"Did she **have** a big family"* though *"Did she **has** a big family"* looks like the correct form? Could someone explain to me why we switch *has* to *have* in questions like that?

Comment: The short answer: Because you already conjugated the verb "do" (into "did").  You don't have to conjugate the other verb.

Answer (score 7):

1. When a verb takes one or more auxiliary verbs, only the first verb in the chain is **finite**: conjugated for tense, person and number. The following verbs are cast in **non-finite** forms: an infinitive or a past or present participle, depending on what construction is employed.
2. When a form of *DO* is employed as an auxiliary verb it is always followed by the **infinitive** form of the main verb.

   > Does she **have** a big family?
   >   Yes, she does **have** a big family.
   >   No, she does not **have** a big family.
   >
   > Did she **have** a big family?
   >   Yes, she did **have** a big family.
   >   No, she did not **have** a big family.

Note that the infinitive form of every verb except **BE** looks the same as the ordinary present form, so it's easy to become confused about this.

Answer (score -1):

> **'has'** is **3rd-person PRESENT tense** only.
>
> **'have'** is **3rd-person PAST tense**.

**DID** is **PAST tense**, hence use **have**.

Comment: I'm afraid not. The past form of *HAVE* in all persons and both numbers is *had*. *Does she have...?* and *Did she have...?* are both correct; the form of *HAVE* used here is the infinitive.

Comment: Oh, true. I failed to think of those. *facepalm